# How to set value in nested BasicDBObject with Java MongoDB driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, nosql

I have a mongo document that I am trying to update before insert in mongodb.

I have to put theses 3 keys

```
document._parentId = ObjectId()
document.aDictionnary.actionId = Integer
document.aDictionnary.bDictionnary.id = Integer
```

I have tried a few combinaison, but can't make it work.

Here is my current code

```
myClass.getDocument().append( "$set", new BasicDBObject().append("_parentId", myClass.getDocument.getId() ) );
myClass.getDocument().append( "$set", new BasicDBObject().append("aDictionnary", new BasicDBObject().append("actionId", actionToAttachId ) ) );

if( null == myClass.getSiteId() )
{
    myClass.getDocument().append( "$set", new BasicDBObject().append("aDictionnary", new BasicDBObject().append("bDictionnary", new BasicDBObject().append( "id", actionToAttach.getSiteId() ))));
}
```

I don't want to directly update my document in database, reason is I keep all the history so each entry is a new insert.

Application doesn't crash, but fail on insert because of a wrong "append" syntax

Also I think it's unpleasing to write that kind of code because of the nested basicdbobject.append syntax, is there another way to do so ?

Here is the stack trace

```
163530 [http-8080-8] ERROR com.myapp.persistance.mystuff.MyClassMongo  - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fields stored in the db can't start with '$' (Bad Key: '$set')
```

Comment: What's the operation you want to do, `update` or `insert`? Full stack trace information will be helpful to analyze the problem.

Comment: @Wizard I have just updated my question

Comment: The error information is clear that field name can't start with **$** because it's a meta character in MongoDB.

Comment: Yes of course I know the error is clear, that's what I explained, and why I didnt post the stack trace at first. Since I am learning to use this library. Unfortunatly, online, most of json manipulation is done with collection.update which is not what I am trying to achieve. I thought using $set (see mykong update for mongodb javadriver) as first param, will overwrite the K/V (second param). do you thing mongodb java driver documentation is full of example ? I can't even find what I am trying to achieve, if you have a link, please provide it

Comment: Just drop that level of `$set` in your codes, for example: `myClass.getDocument().append("_parentId", myClass.getDocument.getId() );` You will achieve that you want. :)

Comment: Thanks @Wizard I will try, but how about replacing values in sub objects ? Can i do like `myClass.getDocument().append("aDictionnary.actionId", myVal )` ?

Comment: I think you'd better learn the basic syntax of MongoDB from the manual of [official website](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/). Most of examples described with js language which is similar to java.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61500/discussion-between-wizard-and-bigdong).

Comment: Yes I have noticed that mongodb java driver just translate from to mongodb syntax. Still, In mongodb i can query subdocument doing key.key.key. Which is not working ` java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fields stored in the db can't have . in them. (Bad Key: 'aDictionnary.actionId')`

Comment: Dot is allowed in query, such as `db.c.find({"a.b.c":1});`; but not allowed as a field name on save or insert, such as `db.c.insert({"a.b.c":1});` is disallowed.

Comment: I joined the chat :) Thanks for clarification, how can I append K/V into subdocuments then ?

Comment: I failed to join the chat perhaps because of the poor net speed. To append K/V into sub-document is just as you almost done, such as `myClass.getDocument().append("aDictionnary", new BasicDBObject().append("actionId", actionToAttachId ) );`

Comment: @wizard, this will not only append the K/V in subdocument, but also erased all others subdocument fields.

Comment: Finally did it using subdocument instead as basicdbobject, instead of new basicdbobject for subdocument, Thanks for yoour help @Wizard, unfortunatly, you didn't post an answer, if you do, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator?

Example:

```
db.students.update({ _id: 1 },{ $push: { scores: 89 }})
```

Comment: this will directly update the database right ? I don't want to update it, since I am keeping the history, every new entry is a new insert. What I am trying to do is update the json, before doing a new insert. Also you're example doesn't append to any sub document.

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

```
document._parentId = ObjectId()
document.aDictionnary.actionId = Integer
document.aDictionnary.bDictionnary.id = Integer
```

Essentially that equates to:

```
{_parentId: ObjectId(), aDictionary: {actionId: actionId,
                                      bDictionnary: {id: id}}
```

So there are 3 documents - the toplevel all the way down to the nested `bDictionnary`.  Each one of these is a `DBObject` so you'd need to build up the `DBObject` and save it as appropriate - here is some untested pseudo code:

```
DBObject myDocument = new BasicDBObject();
myDocument.put("_parentId", ObjectId())
DBObject aDictionary = new BasicDBObject("actionId", actionId)
                           .append("bDictionary", new BasicDBObject("id", id))
myDocument.put("aDictionary", aDictionary)

db.save(myDocument)
```